How do bulk update outdated passwords in iCloud Keychain?
In the past, I moved to using Bitwarden, because Chrome stopped natively supporting iCloud Keychain and I needed something that would work on all devices.
Now I'm using Arc Browser, which does seem to be able to work with iCloud Keychain (I think?) and so I wanted to migrate back to using my iCloud password Keychain as my default password manager.
However, all hundreds of my passwords in my iCloud Keychain are out of date, because I used to use very few passwords for almost every login and ever since I've been slowly replacing every password with a randomly generated one.
So I was hoping I could simply import my Bitwarden passwords into iCloud Keychain, like here:

But unfortunately I can't. Because for every item that already exists, macOS refuses to let that item be overwritten. So what is the alternative? I'm a little afraid to just throw away all my iCloud paswords. Because recently I have also been creating some Passkeys for important accounts which I have stored in iCloud.
